# is there a documentation of the ini-file?

Tags: iri-node

Is there any documentation of the iota.ini-file.
What flags could I set and what does the flags mean?

At the moment, I know only the flags, that are set on the iota.partners installation. But in slack I think I have seen, that there are more flags, that I can set within the ini-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file [Configuration.java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/conf/Configuration.java) of IRI source code you can find all possible configuration parameters for the fullnode even if without any comments.

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't answer what OP asks about. I am also looking for a documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a documentation of all command line options, which are the same as ini file options at https://github.com/iotaledger/iri

Comment: hm, but this seems to be not the hole truth ;)
here are at least 2 more options in my config, that does not lead to an error:

RESCAN_DB = false
REVALIDATE = true